# Unable to Match Using Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, match

I asked this question a while ago, but did not get a proper answer, so giving it another shot.

```
class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String file_name = "C:\\Temp\\Test.txt";
        String string = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(file_name), "UTF-8");
        String regex = "^(ipv6 pim(?: vrf .*?)? rp-address .*)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Matcher: " + matcher.group(1));
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Matches");
        }
    }
}
```

The file contains a lot of lines, more than 750, i guess, I want to extract all the lines that match the regex value. Now the problem is, the way i have done the code, does not return any matches. I only does if the first line of the file matches the regex and nothing else, if its somewhere in the middle, no luck. I thought that since everything is in new line it is causing a problem. But even writing some code converting the string into a single line one does not return a value if the pattern does not match is at the beginning.

A sample matching string: ipv6 pim rp-address 20:20:20::F

Comment: Your regex does not work. Testing it on [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com) proves it. I did a (dirty) matching with : `(ipv6\spim\srp-address\s([\d]{2}:)+:.)`

Comment: I tested it and it does. The leading `^` (Begin of Line) might be a problem if using multiline mode (see below) or if putting all the text in one line.

Comment: @CoronA Well you are right. The problem is the leading ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an if condition, switch it to a while loop.

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Matcher: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

[`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) searches for *one* matching value. To get the next one, you must invoke `find()` again, hence the loop.

Additionally, the `^` prevents you to match again & again as subsequent searches don't match the `starting with` criteria. So you may drop the `^`.

Alternatively, as Rambler suggested use the `Pattern.MULTILINE` flag. This will ensure the `^` is used at the beginning of every new line instead of once at the beginning of the whole string.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving the MULTILINE modifier :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Comment: Unfortunately no luck! :(

Comment: Thanks Vineet/Rambler, combining the two solutions worked! :)

Awesome!